# Displaying Data on Page without refreshing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

MVS 2010 MVC 3:
I have a Submit page that has severial checkboxes that are been built dynamically as soon as the page load. The user can check one or more checkbox before submitting the form. On the right hand side of the page, there is somewhat a summary of all the previous selections that the user chose. The summary is available from the Submit page and will carry to the other pages. There is an "Add Comment" button at the very top of the page. When the user click it, a popup window with a textbox will display allowing the user to type a comment. How do I display this comment on the page without having a refresh the page?
The main reason for not wanting to do a refresh is because the user could have selected one or more checkboxes, they will lose their states as soon as the page is refreshed. 
I tried `parent.document.getElementById('DivCommentResult').html(data);` - It displayed this message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'html': object is null or undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get the parent doucment and retrieve the div id from it. 
Once I have it in hand, I set its innerHTML text to the data that I want to display.

```
var parentDocument = parent.document;
var el = parentDocument.getElementById('commentResult');
```

Once I have this, I simpley call el.innerHTML = data;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you have to bind the change of your check box to a function that submit a synchone ajax request that obtain the summary you need and replace target content with the result data of your request.
Is it what you want ?

Comment: No. I want to display any comment that the user add on the popup window to the parent summary page without having to do a refresh. The below code does it for me when there is data in the div; however, it failed if the div is null or the first time the user adds a comment. 
var parentDocument = parent.document;
var el = parentDocument.getElementById('commentResult');
el.innerHTML = data;